# Почему не срабатывает атрибут rotation() во второй раз?

Tags: java, android

При появлении фото второй машины срабатывает атрибут `animate().rotation()`. Но, если продолжать нажимать на ImageView, то при появлении фото второй машины в следующие разы, оно уже не вращается.

[Видеопример анимации](https://youtu.be/t8z3iPOWXy4)

```
boolean isJetta2Vis = true;

public void earseJetta2(View view) {

    if (isJetta2Vis) {
        ImageView jetta2 = findViewById(R.id.jetta2);
        jetta2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        ImageView jetta6 = findViewById(R.id.jetta6);
        jetta6.animate().alpha(1).rotation(360).setDuration(2000);
        isJetta2Vis = false;
    } else {
        ImageView jetta2 = findViewById(R.id.jetta2);
        jetta2.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
        ImageView jetta6 = findViewById(R.id.jetta6);
        jetta6.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        isJetta2Vis = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было отсчитывать градусы от текущего значения

```
rotation()+360
```